# React: why my links that are inside React components are not working as used to work in pure HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Basically I'm trying to remake some simple web page that I have initially created with HTML and CSS to be working rather on React. I managed to redo the page to correctly display when it was moved into React, however I don't really understand why the navigation links that I have on top do not take me to the corresponding section on the same page anymore as well as why the external links to the project sites also stopped working.

Here is the project link code:

```
import React from "react";

export default function ProjectTile(props) {
return (
  <div className="project-tile" id={props.id}>
    <a href={props.href} target="_blank" id={props.link_id}>
      <img
        className="project_screenshot"
        src={props.img_src}
        alt={props.img_alt}
      />
      <p className="project_name">
        <span className="brackets">&lt;</span> {props.title}{" "}
        <span className="brackets">/&gt;</span>
      </p>
    </a>
  </div>
 );
}
```

All props are getting mapped and loaded from the array with corresponding data where each object looks like this:

```
  {
    id: "tribute_page",
    link_id: "https://codepen.io/konstantinkrumin/full/PooYQbG",
    img_src: "https://i.imgur.com/ynRuzOQ.png",
    img_alt: "tribute_page_screenshot",
    title: "Tribute Page"
  }
```

The navigation links used are the following:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav id="navbar">
    <a className="nav-link" href="#welcome-section">
      About
    </a>
    <a className="nav-link" href="#projects">
      Projects
    </a>
    <a className="nav-link" href="#contact">
      Contact
    </a>
  </nav>
 );
}
```

And each section they refer to have an id corresponding to the href indicated above.

Here if the link to this project on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/konstantinkrumin/static-portfolio-page)

P.S. Everything used to work correctly when it was on HTML.
Also the contact links that seem to be set in similar way as project links are working.

Comment: You need to wrap url inside require("url")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two things I think I found out:

In the `ProjectTile.js` file, replace `href = {props.href}` by `href={props.link_id` and now project opens in codepen.

About the jump link you have made in nav-bar, I think it's because of problem of codesandbox.

If you manage to make your url to `https://op6gq.csb.app#projects` instead of `https://op6gq.csb.app/#projects`. That's gonna work.

Or directly visiting https://op6gq.csb.app/#welcome-section jump link too works well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's no `href` prop. Sounds like what you want is something like

```
href={`#${props.id}`}
```

which would evaluate to `href="#tribute_page"` in this example.

Comment: Thank you! Seems that it is working now. I just missed the href in my link indeed.

I don't seem to be able to figure out how to do the same for those internal links in the navbar.

Answer (score 1):

You Have to try that your page url become:

```
https://op6gq.csb.app#welcome-section
```

Not:

```
https://op6gq.csb.app/#welcome-section
```

please attend to that    **/**  in address bar!

Comment: Could you suggest me please how I could implement it in React?